# android:store image array for record in listview

Tags: android

I want to store array of images for different records.There is a list view for records and when user clicks on particular record new activity is started and i want to display the array images there. How can i do it?

### I tried storing images into draw able folder and using them with R.id but it makes my app heavy.

Comment: Can you post what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

there are several way to dealing with it but not solve it!
1: you can store your image in your assets folder. it can help you to manipulate and working with your images.
2: reduce your image resolutions.
3: create a web server and request your image from the server instead of save them in your local storage.

**also these are not solution but some good trick to deal with this problem!**